# Find the intersection points of a cardioid and a line.

Tags: polar-coordinates

I've been trying to solve a problem that asks for the ratio of two area segments of a cardioid that's "cut" by a line. I think I've got a general idea of how to do it but I've run into a problem when trying to find the intersection points which I believe I need to get the bounds of integration.

One of the points was actually quite easy to find but the other is not.
I'm stuck with the equation:
$$(1-\cos(x))(\cos(x)+2\sin(x)) = 2$$
I know one of the points is at $\theta = \pi/2, r= 1$. I know it's possible to solve for it in cartesian but that requires some fairly advanced algebra and is a lengthy process as the root is not rational.
So my question is: Is there a way to simplify the polar equation into something manageable that i'm simply failing to see?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Take $u = cos(x)$.

We have $(1-u)(u+2\sqrt{1-u^2}) = 2$.

Rearrange for $2\sqrt{1-u^2}(1-u)$ then square both sides.

We have
$-4 u^4 + 8 u^3 - 8 u + 4 = u^4 - 2 u^3 + 5 u^2 - 4 u + 4$
You can see $u=0$ is a root here, which corresponds to $\cos(x) = 0$, $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for example.

This polynomial has another root $u \approx -0.40517$.